# Redefining swap function in inherited classes?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hey I just implemented the big three plus an copy and swap idiom assignment operator in my class.
However, I have some other classes inheriting of this super class, and now I asked myself if I should
redifine this swap method in the sub classes.

Should I make the swap method to privat in every single class?
Should I make the swap method virtual?
What do you guys suggest?

Tyvm!

Header files:

Superclass:

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include <string>

class user
{

public:
  explicit user();
  //user(std::string&, const int);
  user(std::string&, const int, std::string&, std::string&);
  ~user(){};

  // Big three/four...
  user(const user&);   // Copy constructor
  user(user&&);        // move contructor
  user& operator=(user); // Copy/Move assignment
  // + destructor
  
  
  // Swap function for move assignment
  friend void swap(user& first, user& second) 
  {
    std::swap(first.name_m, second.name_m);
    std::swap(first.id_m, second.id_m);
    std::swap(first.class_m, second.class_m);
    std::swap(first.rights_m, second.rights_m);
  }
  
  virtual void printDescription() const;

  void setName(const std::string&);
  void setId(const int);
  void setClass(const std::string&);
  void setRights(const std::string&);

  const std::string& getName() const;
  const int getId() const;
  const std::string& getClass() const;
  const std::string& getRights() const;
  
protected:
  std::string name_m;
  int id_m;
  std::string class_m;
  std::string rights_m;
};

#endif
```

Subclass:

```
#ifndef USER_ADMIN_H
#define USER_ADMIN_H

#include "user.hpp"

#include <string>

struct properties_txt
{
  std::string class_admin = std::string("admin");
  std::string rights_admin = std::string("admin rights");
};

class user_admin : public user
{
public:

  explicit user_admin();
  user_admin(std::string&, const int);
  user_admin(std::string&, const int, std::string&, std::string&);
  ~user_admin();

  user_admin(const user_admin&);
  user_admin(user_admin&&);
  user_admin& operator=(user_admin);

  // Swap function for move assignment
  friend void swap(user& first, user& second)  // Doesnt work obviously
  {
    std::swap(first.name_m, second.name_m);
    std::swap(first.id_m, second.id_m);
    std::swap(first.class_m, second.class_m);
    std::swap(first.rights_m, second.rights_m);
  }
  
  void printDescription() const override;
  
private:
  
};


#endif
```

Just asking whats best

Comment: This seems opinion based to me.

Comment: Rely on move semantics of the whole class and std::swap, don't implement the swap yourself. `user_admin(user_admin&&) = default;` is probably enough with the members you have. Swapping a derived class with an instance of a base would not make sense anyway.

Comment: Side not also make sure to add the move assignment (like you added the copy assignment). `user& operator=(user&&) = default;`

Comment: No I dont want to swap a subclass object with a superclass one. I wanted to implement a swap function for both classes, so I can copy and swap a subclass object with a subclass object or super with super. Is the double ref necessary? I read it would be better to call by value to prevent exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the derived class doesn't add any fields, it shouldn't provide a custom `swap` at all. The one from the base class will be used automatically.

If it did have extra members, the swap should've been implemented as:

```
using std::swap;
swap(static_cast<user &>(first), static_cast<user &>(second));
swap(first.extra, second.extra); // Only swap the fields added in the derived class.
```

---

Some other things:

- Move constructor, copy&swap `operator=`, and `swap()` all should be `noexcept`.
- Unless you're doing this for practice, you should follow the rule of 0 and get rid of all those custom copy/move constructors, assignment operators, and `swap()`. The implicitly generated ones will work just fine.
- Setters should accept parameters by value, then `std::move` them.
- Might be a good idea to get into the habit of writing `using std::swap; swap(...);` instead of calling `std::swap` directly, to be able to utilize custom swap without having to think whether you need to omit `std::` or not for each individual type.

Comment: So if the derived class redefines the swap function should the original swap function be virtual? To verride in hence in the sub class?         Thanks for the other tips, im goind change my code accordingly. Its all jsut for practice mainly btw

Comment: @ArminiusCherusci Friend functions can't be virtual. You can make a virtual member function (as opposed to a friend) to be able to do `a.swap(b)`, but I'd suggest not adding random functions for no reason. Add it if you actually need it.

Comment: Well I would need the function for the assignment in the end. Should i rather implement its content into the assignment operator function?

Comment: @ArminiusCherusci I'd keep it non-virtual by default. I believe a friend swap is slightly better than swapping directly in assignment (could be slightly faster for some types?). But in this case, again, it's better to just remove all those custom operations.